# Integrating a single page application with Ping Federate

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, pingfederate

I have configured IdP and SP in my desktop.To test SSO, I have a single html page deployed in tomcat.I have given the url : http://machinename:portno(here tomcat's port)/webApp/index.html in default url of SP configuration. When I try to hit the SP SSO url,(http://machine_name:portno/sp/startSSO/ping) it redirects to IDP and prompts for authentication. Once the user is authenticated, the user is redirected to the tomcat webpage.

But, when I try to access the tomcat page, I am able to access it without any authentication. Is there any configuration on the SP side? If so, how to do it? When I access the web page, I should be prompted for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration question really has nothing to do with PingFederate. This is more about how you have chosen to integrate your Tomcat application with the PingFederate SP Adapter. Chances are you are using the SP OpenToken or SP ReferenceID Adapter for a Java app in Tomcat- these Adapters merely provide the user's identity attributes to your application after the SAML Response is validated by PingFederate SP. It is up to your application to validate the specific token type (using the proper steps required by the SP Adapter you have chosen) and then your application is also responsible for enforcing access/maintaining a session based upon the user's identity that is passed in the token.

If you are expecting Access Control/Session management, I'd recommend looking at integrating PingFederate with PingAccess.

Bottom Line: Ping's solution's are hugely flexible so there are a number of ways to  accomplish this based upon your application infrastructure and use case requirements. I suggest that you work with your Ping Identity RSA to help you work through these questions in order to have the best possible outcome.